# Can the range of Unclassed Colors go outside the range of the data in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

I am mapping fitted data in ArcGIS Pro, coloring with unclassed colors. My data range between 0.89 and 1, but, in order to compare to other maps, I want to be able to adjust the color range to allow values less than 0.89.  I'm having difficulty changing the data range to allow the legend to show colors corresponding to values outside the range of the data. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In Desktop there is, with a min-max renderer there is a checkbox for *Edit High/Low Values*, if you have this you can enter your own min and max to make the stretch the same. This thread https://community.esri.com/thread/196362-where-is-edit-highlow-values-in-arcgis-pro shows you where it is in Pro.